# How to implement copula portfolio optimization?

Tags: programming, portfolio-optimization, reference-request, copula

This a reference request for any python notebooks, packages or blogs that teach how to do asset allocation using multivariate copulas. How can copula portfolio optimization actually be implemented in code rather than in theory?

Comment: I do not understand why one would be interested in doing mean-variance optimisation with copulas. Isn't the whole point of using variance as a risk measure the fact that in a multivariate normal world it is the only risk measure? And the point of copulas is going beyond multivariate normal?

Comment: distributions don't have to be multivariate normal to have a mean and covariance

Comment: Of course but the relevance of covariance is greatly reduced if you do not have multivariate normals.

Comment: i've removed the word mean-variance from the question

Comment: @gg, if the agent is assumed to have quadratic utility, mean and variance are the only two moments that matter in maximization of expected utility -- regardless of the distribution. This is one of the justifications behind mean-variance optimization.

Comment: @RichardHardy: Yes, you are absolutely right. But if only the first two moments matter to you (for whatever reason) then what use is anything beyond multivariate normals to you?

Comment: @gg, I do not quite see the connection. Assuming multivariate normality when it does not hold will be detrimental in portfolio optimization w.r.t mean and variance.

Comment: Hmm, my thought was: If two portfolios are the same to you if they have the same first two moments, you can always choose a MVN portfolio for your optimisation. MVN distributions contains all possible first and second moments and by definition you would not/could not distinguish the non-MVN from the MVN portfolio since you only use first and second moments and those are identical. So what could possibly be detrimental?